# Separating Comma-Separated Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have a string containing the value `"12,13"`
I want 2 strings from this string i.e
`s1 = 12` and 
`s2 = 13`

how can I separate in asp.net C#?

I have not much time to google it that's why I am posting it here.
Hope anyone can answer this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
string firstString = "12,13";
string[] values = firstString.Split(',');

string s1 = values[0];
string s2 = values[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string numbersText ="12,13"
string[] numbers= numbersText.Split(','); 
if(numbers.Length >= 2) // check length of array if you not sure about text before access items of it 
{
    string s1 =numbers[0];
    string s1 =numbers[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.Split() method

example:

```
string text = "12,13";
string[] parts = text.Split(',');

string s1 = parts[0]; // "12"
string s2 = parts[1]; // "13"
```